# will 0x exchange proxy every refund eth?

Tags: 0x

I'm currently designing my contract to work with 0x Swap API, but not sure if I should handle the case of refund. (it's kind of tricky for me to add a fallback because i'm using the diamond proxy pattern)
So my question is, is it possible that I can expect the 0x swap api give me a calldata that will never return eth? Like is there a way to specify all refund in weth or something.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify, by "refund" do you mean the `estimatedGasTokenRefund` response field? If so, I don't think there's a way to change that.

If you were just looking to wrap any eth returned in a swap quote, you could do so by requesting a swap quote with `sellToken` and `buyToken` as 'WETH' or 'ETH'. The swap quote returned will provide the calldata to directly interact with the `WETH9` contract and not with 0x exchange contracts ([code example](https://docs.0x.org/0x-api-swap/api-references/get-swap-v1-quote#wrapping-and-unwrapping-between-eth-and-weth)).